# Someone answered a question 9 years ago, but the profile shows "member for 4 months"

Tags: support, answers, users, timestamps

Looking at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57874257/4385621) one can see that it was written in Sep 2010, but when clicking on the answerer link it shows the profile of a member who has been a "Member for 4 months".

[image]

How could someone create an account in 2019 and answer a question in 2010, assuming there is no time-machine (if we had, there would already be a Stack Overflow tag for that)? Or does the "Member for 4 months" mean something else than when the account was first created?

Comment: The answer was posted on September 10, of 2019. Not in September of 2010.

Comment: By the way, the tag [time-machine] exists on MSO, but it's for a different topic ;)

Comment: @honk Gosh, [time-travel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/time-travel) too!

Comment: Interestingly the mobile app shows the date correctly as "10 Sep", only the website uses the confusing format.

Comment: Erm, this isn't "no repro", at least not until Jan 1st of 2020.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

I think you are referring to the usercard below the [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57874257/2675154) in question:

[image: Usercard]

Here, "Sep 10" means the 10th of September 2019, so the answer is just 5 weeks old.  If the answer would have been, for example, from the first September in 2010, it would read "Sep 1 '10".

To avoid confusion, you can hover over the date to get the following popup:

[image: Timestamp]

This date formatting is more readable (at least to me).

Comment: Precisely! I mistook _10_ for the year, not the day! In short, more recent answers do contain the time, but not the year and older ones, hide the time but show the year? Is it just me, or would it be more user-friendly to have one date format, no matter how old the post is?

Comment: I guess you are right. I misread the dates quite often...

Comment: It's trying to be "friendly" and easy to read. Just like the way it says "20 mins ago", instead of giving you the exact time. When it was posted within the same year, the year is omitted; you're supposed to be able to assume that it was the month and day within the current year. And when posts are more than a year old, the exact time at which it was posted really doesn't matter, so that information gets hidden by default. You can hover over it to see a consistently-formatted timestamp. (cc @gmauch)

Comment: @gmauch It's a matter of relevancy, something I think is completely missing in (usually) non-American systems of measurement. In the US we give the most relevant information for a date based on when you are asking in comparison to the date. If today is 15 Oct 2019, and something is happening on 31 Oct 2019, we say "it's happening on Oct 31st/the 31st/in about two weeks", because the year is not relevant in this situation. If something is happening on 15 April 2020, we say "April 15th of next year" or "April 15th, 2020"--we don't say "it's happening in 28 weeks", because that's less useful.

Comment: @CodyGray: Your reasoning is perfectly logical and I understand, why it was done this way. I anyway get confused from time to time. Maybe, because I'm not so used to this notation...

Comment: That's fascinating. I personally find the plain timestamp to be very confusing and difficult to read. There's a lot of information packed in there, most of which is irrelevant to me at the time, yet I have to dig through it all with my eyes and make sense of it with my brain. It's interesting, though, because your viewpoint is exactly the opposite. Which just goes to show that it's all what you get used to (said the old lady, as she kissed her cow).

Comment: @CodyGray For me at least, the timestamp is far more legible and parseable to my brain.

Comment: @VictorStafusa: In my country, dates are usually formatted in the following order: day, month, year. So, if I spot a number behind a month, I might misinterpret it as year out of habit.

Comment: @CodyGray - Perhaps an easier alternative would be along the lines of dd-mmm-yyyy, or simply the time if it was posted today. Having a single format makes life easier.